# Prisma getting Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`3306` error on Dockerized nestjs

Tags: node.js, docker, nestjs, prisma

When i dockerized `Nestjs` with `MySql` and `phpMyadmin` i getting this error on console:

```
Error: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`3306`
at r /usr/src/app/node_modules/.pnpm/@prisma+client@4.15.0_prisma@4.15.0/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:108:2574)
```

migrating and seeding database is fine but this this code doesn't work:

```js
async signUp(@Body() dto: AuthDto):Promise<any> {
  return await this.prisma.user.findUnique(
      {
        where: {
          mobileNumber: dto.mobileNumber
        }
      }
  );
}
```

migrating and seeding:

```
➜  my_app git:(master) ✗ npx prisma db push --force-reset && npx prisma db seed

Datasource "db": MySQL database "my_app" at "localhost:3306"

The MySQL database "my_app" at "localhost:3306" was successfully reset.

npm notice
Environment variables loaded from .env
Running seed command `ts-node prisma/seed.ts` ...

  The seed command has been executed.
```

`docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
networks:
  host:
    name: my_app
    external: true
  lan_access:
    driver: bridge
    
services:
  my_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src/Dockerfile
      target: development
    command: npm run start:dev my_app
    env_file:
      - src/.env

    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    networks:
      - default
    ports:
      - '80:3000'

  database:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'my_db'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'root'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
volumes:
  my-db:
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
# Development stage
FROM node:alpine As development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY prisma ../../prisma/

RUN npm install -g pnpm
RUN pnpm install --save

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

# Production stage
FROM node:alpine as production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY prisma ../../prisma/

RUN npm install -g pnpm
RUN pnpm install --only=production

COPY . .

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
COPY --chown=node:node --from=builder /usr/src/app/prisma /prisma


CMD ["node", "dist/src/amanpaz/main"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're running the server inside a docker-compose project, you should use the database service's name as the host to make use of docker compose's internal DNS resolution. Using the host `database` in your server's env should fix the error